# Python - add a dynamic debug logger style line number and time function

Tags: python, alias

The following function that reports the "current" line-number (and time) which I would like to call from within other functions when a runtime Exception occurs.

Understandably the line number returned always relates to the position of getframeinfo within the gTime() function itself, i.e. it's static.

I simply want the gTime() functionality whenever I require the line.num/time data *without directly adding the (long) gTime code* into each position where it's required within the main code body. I guess some sort of **command sequence alias** is what I am really looking for to substitute the code within my gTime() function - but can't find any solution to my problem.

The standard 'logger' module won't work reliably within my multi-threaded application so I am resorting to a hand-rolled solution.

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
from datetime import datetime

def gTime():
    position = "%s [%s] - " % (str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").rstrip('0')),getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno)
    return position 

print gTime()
```

Comment: Why you don't like standard python `logging` module?

Comment: Like I said "The standard 'logger' module won't work reliably within my multi-threaded application so I am resorting to a hand-rolled solution." - I am suffering from this bug http://bugs.python.org/issue11444 and can't get our libraries updated for internal reasons

Comment: Concurent log handler also will not help? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConcurrentLogHandler/0.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use `logging`, I'd suggest using as much as you can of its internals or at least learning from them; see http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/logging/__init__.py.

In particular, `logging.currentframe` can be used to get an enclosing frame:

```
from inspect import getframeinfo
from logging import currentframe
from datetime import datetime

def callingFrame():
    return getframeinfo(currentframe())

def gTime():
    position = "%s [%s] - " % (str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").rstrip('0')), callingFrame().lineno)
    return position 

print gTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

"The standard 'logger' module won't work reliably within my multi-threaded application so I am resorting to a hand-rolled solution."

The [documentation disagrees](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#thread-safety)

> The logging module is intended to be thread-safe without any special
>   work needing to be done by its clients. It achieves this though using
>   threading locks; there is one lock to serialize access to the module’s
>   shared data, and each handler also creates a lock to serialize access
>   to its underlying I/O.

Why doesn't it work reliably?

Comment: I am suffering from this bug bugs.python.org/issue11444 and can't get our libraries updated for internal reasons, so in the meantime I am looking at an alternate solution. I would also like to hear more about the potential of a "command sequence alias" in general.